# selenium webdriver python: opening chrome browser to run test case does not load the saved settings of the browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a selenium test case in Chrome browser. Before this i have set the default download location for files of chrome browser to say f:/xyz

When the selenium script is run, which clicks on a link to download a file - it downloads in the chrome's default location (c:/documents and settings/downloads) and not in the f:/xyz which i have set earlier

How to correct this ?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, the problem here is that the download location is associated with a specific user profile, and the Chrome driver follows the same pattern as the Firefox driver in that by default, it uses a copy of a completely clean user profile every time it is run, so the download location you set for your user is never picked up by Selenium.  In Firefox, the solution is to create a custom Firefox profile, then tell Selenium to run with that.  I'd bet there is an analogous function in the Chrome driver.

According to [docs](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/directory"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Yes that is Java, but it should be fairly easy to translate to Python.  Also, note the docs say that there is a known bug about being able to set a custom profile.

Edit:

I think I found a mildly hacky solution that should work for you.

1. Go to the master folder that contains user/home folders on the OS you are running under
2. Under the SYSTEM user folder, find the [Chrome user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)
3. Open the Preferences file (it's raw text, so any text editor will work)
4. Under the "download" node, create or modify the "default_directory" node to be whatever download location you want

Note that these steps assume that Selenium has actually run Chrome at least once under the SYSTEM user.  If not, you can manually create the directories needed by running Chrome under the SYSTEM user yourself, from the terminal for instance.

Comment: yes - No where am able to find a example of python + chrome opening a existing profile which has download location configured. Tried the following - but no good 
 opts = Options()
 opts.add_argument("--user-data-dir 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\ Data\Default'")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done at the time. From the official ChromeDriver Wiki at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver:

Known Issues
There are a handful of known issues with ChromeDriver, listed below:

1. Can only retrieve the name and value of set cookies (no domain, path, etc.)
2. Typing does not work with rich-text enabled documents.
3. **Cannot specify a custom profile**
4. HTML 5 API not implemented