# Accept request to microphone in Chrome using selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing selenium tests python using webdriver and my test cases require access to user media (microphone). I tried different variations of [--disable-user-media-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628904/accept-permission-request-in-chrome-using-selenium) flag but couldn't achieve what I want. I'm doing something this:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-user-media-security")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xxx/Develop/WebME/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = self.driver
```

Any ideas on how to handle this? There must be some way to do get access to mic :/

Answer (score 0):

For microphone, add this option to chrome:

`chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")`