# Cypress accept browser permissions like audio

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

Is it possible in cypress to ask for the browser permissions? I have tried asking the permissions. A dialog prompt from browser pops in, but I am unable to click on the permission.

And what will be the behaviour when it runs headless? like in CI where usually we don't have video recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyboard shortcuts to click the permissions as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21686531/6563764